# how to set image width to clientHeight x 5.128571428571429

Tags: javascript, image

I have a script where I need to set the width of an img tag to the clientHeight of the img tag.

This is my code:

```
var logo = document.getElementById("logoImg");
logo.width = logo.clientHeight * 5.128571428571429 + "px";
```

If the clientHeight of the img tag is 70px, then the width of it should by set to 359px, how could I this.

Comment: Your code should work... What's the problem that you have encountered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Width should be set to a number, not a string. Try this instead:

```
logo.width = logo.clientHeight * 5.128571428571429;
```